# CPU overheating in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature, fancontrol

I updated my ubuntu 22.04 to ubuntu 22.10 but now i have a problem.
In previos version my maximum cpu's temperature was 40° but in this version Suddenly the temperature rises to 80° then my fan speed increases it's while i dont run any program.

Comment: please add a bit more information,type of pc-at what temperature is your CPU during the speed increase and can you read the fan speed of your system?

Comment: you should edit the information into your question,an overheating cpu is important information.

Comment: So what is the hardware?

Comment: Check your firmware is current. If it isn't, update it. This often affects power-management issues.

Comment: There is no new update for this version yet